# Write conflict on updating form checkbox with multi-table view as recordsouce

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I have created a form with a View as recordsource, this view combines 1 table and another view (with 2 tables in it). 
When the checkbox is clicked a validation happens in the Access code that checks if the records checkbox may be updated, if this is not the case then the checkbox value should change back to 0/false.

First I tried to do this simply in the `click event` of the checkbox and then setting the `checkbox value = false` when it does not validate. This however gives a `write conflict`. Next I tried it with a `Me.Dirty = false` in front of it, this also doesn't help (still getting the write conflict). The `checkbox.undo` gives the same result.

Then I thought to do it in the `before update` and use a simple `cancel=true`, this however causes the focus not to change (it keeps the focus on the same record and never moves from it).

The `Timestamp` is usually what I use to ignore write conflict messages, I included the timestamp of the main table but this doesn't work (probably because the view is multiple-table based).

Some additional info:

- The view is created in the SQL server and is linked to Access
- The primary keys of the view (so it is editable) are set by executing a CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement

Any ideas how I can get this to work?

Comment: *"and then setting the checkbox value = false"* did you do this with an UPDATE SQL? If you instead set the form checkbox value, there shouldn't be a write conflict, since the record isn't written.

Comment: SQL Server uses 1 and 0 whereas MS Access uses -1 and 0. Do you have code to make this happen?

Comment: @Fionnuala when setting a checkbox control to true/false directly this doesn't matter since the controlsource behind it is the bit field from the sql server and access does the translation itself (correctly).

Comment: Not in my experience. Perhaps I am using an older version of SQL Server.

Comment: @Andre no, this isn't being done with an update statement, it is done directly to the controlsource / checkbox control, the record is in matter of fact 'written' since the onclick event checks/fills the control and by doing that also sets the underlying controlsource behind it (so it is saved) - this is done automatically by access. Then I uncheck it again (in code) if it isn't valid (checkbox=false).

Comment: I should mention that I have a very similar set-up for one client and do not get write conflicts. This is why i suspect that you have some code that is causing the problem, as, it seems, does Andre.

Comment: I don't understand. If the user clicks a bound checkbox, how is its controlsource changed? Or the record automatically saved? Please post the full code you have/had for *"First I tried to do this simply in the click event of the checkbox"* - this should be the right way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by using a button to set the checkbox bound field to checked/unchecked and making the checkbox itself invisible. This seems to work (better).